# Can we keep different themes for different pages in react with styled components website?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have used useColorMode() hooks from ChakraUi to toggle themes, but on a new project, while working with styled components, my client wanted to have light themes on few pages, while dark theme on other. Can anyone help me with this?

Need to have fixed themes for various pages in my react website, without using toggle buttons.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please, provide a reproducible example and more details of why you aren't managing to solve your problem. I recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips. Just remember, "Questions asking for homework help are not inherently off-topic. However, you must have made a good faith attempt to solve it yourself.", as stated into [On-topic answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You'd need to provide a different theme for the different pages, which can be done by wrapping said pages with a `ThemeProvider`.